# Content with display:none displays before css loads in Safari

Tags: html, css, display

```css
.video-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.modal-body {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>OTHER CONTENT</div>
    <div class="video-modal">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <video src="" controls></video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have some elements one my page that are display:none that I am showing on click. On Chrome everything works as expected, but on Safari the elements flash on the screen quickly as the page loads. I am guessing that the html is loading before the css file processes and the rules are set. But why is this happening and why only in Safari? Also why are these elements loading and showing on screen before any other html elements on the page? See image for example (this image is of video modals that I have hidden with display:none and are showing on click).

[image]

[image]

EDIT: here is Repl showing issue, note: must be in Safari. https://repl.it/@teeej/ReliablePunctualRam

Comment: The image is helpful but post your code and css, it will be more helpful

Comment: are your script tags in your header?

Comment: @JakeG The css file is the scripts are at end of body.

Comment: Try moving them to your header

Comment: @Huangism Added edit to question, here is repl showing the issue: https://repl.it/@teeej/ReliablePunctualRam, must be in safari

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question, not just on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable piece of code here on Stack Overflow so people don't need to navigate elsewhere, and the question will make sense when that link goes dead.

Comment: I tried the link in safari on a mac, I don't see any flashes

Comment: @JakeG That does seem to work even though there is nothing in my script file? Can you shed any light why?

Comment: @Huangism I don't know what to say. I see it happening every time I hit the run button, and the same issue arises on my actual site.

Comment: @taptaptap I am on a fairly good machine with really fast internet speed but that shouldn't matter that much. You could try putting the display none as inline styles and see if that makes a difference. But with your css in the head tag, this shouldn't happen

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done. But you will not see the issue unless you open the repl and run on Safari

Comment: @Huangism Yes I did figure about going the inline style route but would rather not have to do that and wanted to get to the root problem of why it is happening. My machine is fast as well and it is happening even locally.

Comment: @taptaptap you said moving js to head worked, so problem solved? Safari probably just renders differently so when it is going thru the js at the end of the page it didn't apply the css yet. Hard to say why for sure, these are the inner workings of a browser which I have no idea about

Comment: This is generally called FOUC or [Flash of Unstyled Content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). A little searching on that term should help find a ton of techniques to resolve it.

Comment: @Huangism Yes the interesting this is the issue still happens if there is no javascript files whatsoever. But when I add even an empty js file to the head it fixes the issue. I guess we can counted the issue fixed but still curious about why this is happening.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok thanks.